# How to pass the data into the text-fields

Tags: php, yii

I am trying to write the code for parsing the uploaded `.csv` file. I have written the following code. The controller generates the rows of the CSV file in the form of arrays which I have also tried to print with `print_r($buffer);` statement and I get the expected output. Though the strings can be printed using `echo $string;`, but I am not able to pass them to the text-fields for editing before saving to the database.

**SiteController**

```
public function actionImport()
{
    $buffer[] = array();
    if(isset($_POST['submitCSV'])){
        $filename=$_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $fp = fopen("$filename","r");
            if($fp){
                $i = 0;
                while(($buffer[$i++] = fgetcsv($fp,1000,",")) !== false)
                {}
                if(!feof($fp))
                    echo "Echo: Unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
            fclose($fp);
            unset($_POST['submitCSV']);
    }
    $this->render('index',array('buffer'=>$buffer));
}
```

**View(index.php)**

```
<div class="form">
<?php echo CHtml::beginForm('site/import',$method='post',$htmlOptions =array('enctype'=>'multipart/form-data')); ?>

    <div class="row">
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="30000" />
        <input type="file" name="filename" value="file">
        <?php
            echo CHtml::submitButton('Submit', array('name'=>'submitCSV'));
            foreach($buffer as $line)
                foreach($line as $string)
                    echo CHtml::activeTextField($string,$htmlOptions = array('value'=>$string));
        ?>
</div>
<?php echo CHtml::endForm(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, try something like:

```
public function actionImport()
{
    if (isset($_POST['submitCSV'])) {
        $filename = $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'];
        $fp = fopen("$filename", "r");
        if($fp) {
            while(($buffer = fgetcsv($fp,1000,",")) !== false)
            {
            }
            if(!feof($fp)) {
               echo "Echo: Unexpected fgets() fail\n";
            }
        }
        fclose($fp);
        if (count($buffer)) {
            $this->render('index',array('buffer' => $buffer));
        }
    }
}
```

And in your view:

```
<? foreach ($buffer as $line): ?>

   <p><? CHtml::activeTextField($line, array('class' => 'login_textbox', 'style' => 'width:100%', 'value' => $line)); ?> </p>

<? endforeach; ?>
```

You're passing an array of data (composed of your CSV lines) to your view, which is then iterating over the array and rendering a text field for each one. Make sure you have short_tags enabled.

Comment: How would the view know that I have sent some array with data?  and BTW i get this `error : undefined variable $buffer`.

Comment: You need to view [Yii's documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/249/understanding-the-view-rendering-flow/) about their view rendering

Comment: according to the documentation, i need a model to be defined. But right now since I don't want to save the data into the database, why would i need the model?

Comment: A model need not be a CActiveRecord. You can simply using a CModel object. That is what Yii's default login and contact pages do - those don't save to the database either. See ContactForm and LoginForm in the models folder for examples.

Comment: @hohner I have edited the question. I wasn't able to figure out earlier what was the problem. Now I have specified the issue more clearly.

Comment: Why are you trying to do 2 nested foreach loops in your view? You're also trying to echo PHP variables in single quotes. Please look at my answer

Comment: i have changed the code, please have a look at my code again. I am using a 2-dimensional array and I have corrected the issue.

Comment: @hohner the problem with your code is: that `fgetcsv` will return `array` on every iteration, so the `$buffer` obtained is the last array generated by `while` loop. In your code, the `$buffer` is getting over-written. You must haven't noticed.