# Update existing .CSV or Excel document using data from Javascript

Tags: javascript, csv

I have been using the CSVToArray() Function as found here:
[Javascript code to parse CSV data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1293147/javascript-code-to-parse-csv-data)

The following code creates a download link to a .csv file that contains data from a string.

```
window.URL = window.URL || window.webkiURL;
var blob = new Blob([csv]);
var blobURL = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
$("#downloadLink").html("");
$("<a></a>").
attr("href", blobURL).
attr("download", "data.csv").
text("Download CSV").
appendTo('#downloadLink');
```

My question is how can I save the data from my string to a current .csv or excel spreadsheet? My aim is to get the data auto-populated into a basic template.

Comment: I think you should arrange this server-side and use ajax calls to let it work seamless. What server-side language are you using?

Comment: Have you looked at uploading and parsing csv/Excel in PHP? Like so: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593473/how-to-upload-and-parse-a-csv-file-in-php