# Uploading a CSV. file to Wamp by a online application?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, csv

I was wondering if anyone could either guide me or know where can I find out how to create a "submit form" of some sort to upload CSV. file to a primitive online application.

Basically it is a little proyect I am doing to learn Html, Css, Js and Php. I wanted to be able to load user info into the application and I was told that a good way was using .CSV (which I didn´t even know it existed).

I have no idea how would to make a browse button to find the root of the file and even less how to validate it. For what I could find this is the code I need to add in SQL(Wamp server in my case):

```
-- Seteamos el formato de fecha para que funcione correctamente este fichero
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
GO

-- This is to import I assume.
BULK
INSERT CSVUsers
FROM 'D:\users.CSV'
WITH

(
-- This is to set the separations I think.
FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',
--s is to separate the registry I deduct
ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
);
GO
```

I don´t know if I am missing something here besides the obvious upload thing.So frustrating...

Thanks a lot in advance.
Best Wishes

Comment: http://www.tizag.com/phpT/fileupload.php

Comment: Do you know is that upload size is enough for a csv. file? Also thanks for the swift reply.

Comment: I assume you are referring to `<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000" />`. I actually suggest you do not use that. It is a PHP idiosyncrasy that isn't helpful, and may have been deprecated long ago (I don't know, I was a PHP junky 5 years ago.)

Comment: Check out the question to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593473/how-to-upload-and-parse-a-csv-file-in-php