# Uploading CSV using PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, xml

I have a table on my webpage.

I want to add more data by adding an import CSV button with that.

The CSV's I will import would be exactly formatted in the manner the table is.

So, how can I insert an upload button which could save the CSV temporarily and call a PHP code which can then upload the table?

Comment: I haven't tried anything. I just had a brief idea as to use the form action attribute and so on. But, is there a better way?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please consider reading [ask] if you want to have a better chance of getting help. Your questions need to be to-the-point, show that you've made an effort yourself to solve the problem (i.e. show us your code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// check this url I hope it's useful ...

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5593473/how-to-upload-and-parse-a-csv-file-in-php
```

OR

```
https://www.codexworld.com/import-csv-file-data-into-mysql-database-php/
```