# CSV as 2d array

Tags: php

whats good and simply way to convert csv file to 2d array, where i will be able to get value with

```php
$rownumber=1;
$columnnumber=1;
foreach ($array['rows'] as $row) {
  foreach ($row as $value) {
    print($array[$rownumber][$columnnumber]);
  }
  print('<br>');
}
```

I've tried

```php
$f = $_FILES["file"]['tmp_name'];
//move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],'tmp/'.$_FILES['file']['name']);
$csvData=file_get_contents($_FILES['file']['tmp_name']);
$array['rows']=explode("\n",$csvData);
foreach ($array['rows'] as $value) {
  $array['rows']['values'] = explode(';',$value);
}
```

But i cant get exact column from row im currently on.

Comment: so you want to declare an array per row? seems a bit.. inefficient

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5593885/6556397

Comment: https://pastebin.com/xK9t4QXa edited code, it works, but does it look fine?