# How do I get blob of uploaded image using php?

Tags: php, html, image, blob

I have an html form. Inside of that form there is an input with `type="file"` and `accept="image/*"`.  When the form gets submitted the value of the input is saved to a php variable.

How can I get blob of the uploaded image using php?
I only need to get the blob of the image so I can store it to a database. I can do everything else necessary for uploading the file.

I have looked at [Quick php file upload guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3696803/quick-php-file-upload-guide?lq=1) and none of the answers there helped me.

Comment: @TiesonT. this is not a duplicate because this is asking a specific question about how to get something done. That was asking for a tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Replace 'uploadfieldname' with the actual name of the upload field

```
echo file_get_contents($_FILES['uploadfieldname']['tmp_name'])
```

Answer (score -1):

You have a similar question if i am not wrong: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17122270

```
$directory = "mytheme/images/myimages";
$images = glob($directory . "*.jpg");

foreach($images as $image)
{
  echo $image;
}
```

Comment: Well, this doesn't actually get the blob of the image. This is not the kind of answer that I was looking for.